# PMML sklearn2pmml error in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pmml

I have a randomforest model that I am trying to convert into a pmml. I could fit the model properly, as it doesn't throw any errors:

```
test_pipeline = PMMLPipeline([("rforest", RandomForestClassifier())])
test_pipeline.fit(trainX, trainY)

CPU times: user 1.18 s, sys: 61.6 ms, total: 1.24 s
Wall time: 1.25 s
```

However I get an error when I try to call the sklearn2pmml method:

```
sklearn2pmml(test_pipeline, "DecisionTreeIris.pmml", with_repr = True)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-9f07cfed11da> in <module>()
----> 1 sklearn2pmml(test_pipeline, "DecisionTreeIris.pmml", with_repr = True)

/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/__init__.pyc in sklearn2pmml(pipeline, pmml, user_classpath, with_repr, debug)
     89                 if(debug):
     90                         print(" ".join(cmd))
---> 91                 subprocess.check_call(cmd)
     92         finally:
     93                 if(debug):

/Users/dileeppatchigolla/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    539         if cmd is None:
    540             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 541         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    542     return 0
    543 

CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-cp', '/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/guava-19.0.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/istack-commons-runtime-2.21.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/jcommander-1.48.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/jpmml-converter-1.2.0.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/jpmml-lightgbm-1.0.0.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/jpmml-sklearn-1.2.3.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/jpmml-xgboost-1.1.4.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/pmml-agent-1.3.4.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/pmml-model-1.3.4.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/pmml-model-metro-1.3.4.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/pmml-schema-1.3.4.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/pyrolite-4.15.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/serpent-1.16.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar:/Users/dileeppatchigolla/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/resources/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.22.jar', 'org.jpmml.sklearn.Main', '--pkl-pipeline-input', '/var/folders/1j/5zzgmlk16ql5mm9z6_3n0c840000gp/T/pipeline-G164OK.pkl.z', '--repr-pipeline', "PMMLPipeline(steps=[('rforest', RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',\n            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,\n            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,\n            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,\n            oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,\n            warm_start=False))])", '--pmml-output', 'DecisionTreeIris.pmml']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Can someone help me debug the error logs and provide a solution?

Comment: The original issue never got resolved as we moved on from the problem. I faced the issue again after several months, and this time found the reason - 
The jdk in my Mac is of 1.6 version while sklearn2pmml has a min requirement of 1.7; I have updated jdk and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be accessing `sklearn2pmml` functionality from within IPython notebook. This function executes a Java process (as can be seen from the last line of your error report), and checks whether this Java process returns exit code 0 (success) or -1 (failure).

The most probable cause for returning exit code -1 is that some sort of Java exception was thrown. The Java process prints the full stack trace of such exceptions to its "standard" output stream. Apparently, the IPython notebook doesn't know how to capture and transmit it - you're only seeing Python's "front-end" exception, and not Java's "back-end" exception.

Your error report does not contain any actionable information (and is not a reproducible example). Please check the raw logs of your IPython notebook, and see what the Java "back-end" exception really was. What happens if you execute your Python script straight from the command-line?

Comment: Yes, I was working in an IPython notebook. But I got the same error when I tried from command-line as well.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the associated Java exception?

Comment: I don't know where I can find it. Can you please help me how to fetch it?

Comment: Just execute your Python script from the command line, and capture its "standard" output and error streams to some file: `python script.py > log.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: The original issue never got resolved as we moved on from the problem. I faced the issue again after several months, and this time found the reason - 
The jdk in my Mac is of 1.6 version while sklearn2pmml has a min requirement of 1.7; I have updated jdk and the issue is fixed.