# Generating PMML from Sklearn models in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pmml

I wanted to convert an Sklearn model to PMML format, using the [sklearn2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package. I meet all requirements and I believe I use the functions right, but I keep running into the same error.

This is the code I use to create the model.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn2pmml import PMMLPipeline

lm = PMMLPipeline([("regression", LinearRegression())])
lm.fit(training, trainTarget)
```

So far, everything works. But whenever I want to write the pmml as below, it raises a CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd), showing a block of paths and other stuff, with the last line saying 'returned non-zero exit status 1'.

```
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml
sklearn2pmml(lm, "MetricModelDemo.pmml", with_repr=True)
```

Anyone who could help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698871/pmml-sklearn2pmml-error-in-python2-7

Comment: You'll need to provide more details on the Java exception that was thrown. You can try running the Java command described in the raised `CalledProcessError` or piping stderr to a file.